# i am stuck on showing the function g(i) = h(i) if i < j and g(i) = h(i+1) if $i\geq j$ is surjective Tao Proposition 7.1.8

Tags: real-analysis, functions

in Tao's **Proposition 7.1.8 (Finite summations are well-defined)**

at the end of the proof we need to show that:

let h be a bijective function from {i ∈ N : $1 \leq i \leq n+1$} to the set X where h(j) := x

define g to be the function from {i ∈ N : $1 \leq i \leq n$} to X\{x}

where g(i) = h(i) if i < j and g(i) = h(i+1) if $i\geq j$

I keep running into troubles showing surjectivity

for example let z ∈ X\{x} hence z ∈  X so there exists some i in  {i ∈ N : $1 \leq i \leq n+1$} where h(i) = z

now if i < j we are done since g(i) = h(i) when $i \geq j$ I'm running into problems since "i" cannot equal "j" and if i > j we have g(i) = h(i+1) how does g(i) ever equal z?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have $i=j$ since otherwise, $z=h(i)=h(j)=x$. Therefore, $z\notin X\setminus\{x\}$. The only cases you need to consider are $i<j$ and $j>i$.

Comment: right so perhaps when i > j then $i \geq j +1$ hence $i-1 \geq j$ so g(i-1) = h(i) = z

Comment: You are correct